# UITextView in collectionview cell on mac spikes cpu

Tags: macos, uicollectionview, uitextview

I have a simple UIKit application that has a `UITextView` in a `UICollectionViewCell`. The app is designed for iOS/iPadOS and works just fine on those platforms. However, when run on Mac (Designed for iPad) as soon as I start scrolling the collectionview, the cpu usage spikes to ~85% and stays there indefinitely. The only way to lower the cpu is to click outside of the application window, but once it comes to the foreground again, the cpu usage jumps right back up. I've tried running on Mac in Catalyst mode too, but the same problem occurs with slightly less cpu usage (~45%).

Additionally the debugger constantly spits out `[API] cannot add handler to 3 from 3 - dropping` while scrolling.

Does anyone have an explanation or solutions for this?

I’m using Xcode Version 14.1 (14B47b) on macOS Ventura 13.0 (22A380).

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, String>! = nil
    var collectionView: UICollectionView! = nil
    var items = Array(0...100).map{"Item \($0)"}
    
    enum Section: String {
        case main
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "List"
        configureCollectionView()
        configureDataSource()
        applyInitialSnapshot()
    }
    
    private func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { sectionIndex, layoutEnvironment in
            let size = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .estimated(100))
            let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: size)
            let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: size, subitems: [item])
            
            return NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        }
    }
    
    private func configureCollectionView() {
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: createLayout())
        collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }
    
    private func configureDataSource() {
        let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<TestCell, String> { (cell, indexPath, item) in
            cell.configure(title: item, row: indexPath.item)
        }
        
        dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, String>(collectionView: collectionView) {
            (collectionView, indexPath, identifier) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
            
            return collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: cellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: identifier)
        }
    }
    
    private func applyInitialSnapshot() {
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, String>()
        snapshot.appendSections([.main])
        snapshot.appendItems(items)
        
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
    }
}
```

```swift
class TestCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    private let annotationsTextView = UITextView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addViews()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func configure(title: String, row: Int) {
        annotationsTextView.attributedText = .init(string: "Row: \(row) Item: \(title)", attributes: [.font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1)])
    }
    
    private func addViews() {
        annotationsTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
        annotationsTextView.isEditable = false
        annotationsTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        contentView.addSubview(annotationsTextView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            annotationsTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            annotationsTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
            annotationsTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            annotationsTextView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  contentView.trailingAnchor),
        ])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am still on 13.0.1 and had the same problem (tons of [API] cannot add handler to 3 from 3 - dropping). I narrowed it down to a call to `UITableView.scrollToNearestSelectedRow with animated = true`.

Setting animated to false stops the logging. I guess I’ll have to check out 13.1

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing this exact behavior in Ventura whenever there is a UITextView anywhere in the view hierarchy with either isSelectable or isEditable set to true, but only while the UITextView is NOT first responder. This occurs whether the UITextView is visible or hidden.

The excess CPU usage can be prevented by any of the following:

- Remove the UITextView from the view hierarchy.
- Set isSelectable AND isEditable to false.
- Make the UITextView first responder.

I'm still investigating and will update here if I find more. We should all probably report the issue to Apple as I imagine they will need to fix this at the system level.

**2022-12-01: Update**

This issue appears to have been resolved as of macOS 13.1 beta 4 (22C5059b). Hallelujah!

Comment: I've submitted feedback (FB11749476) on November 3rd. Hopefully this can get fixed soon.

Comment: I've also reported to Apple (FB11797487) on November 16th, complete with sample project and video showing behavior. Let's hope for the best!

Comment: Here is the sample code and video: https://github.com/jeffreyfultonca/UITextViewHighCPUUsage